# Default column values per content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, document-set, default-value

I remember doing this in the past but now I can't get default values to populate in my columns dependent on the content type.

My structure is this:

1. Library
2. Document Set
3. New > A variety of content types

I have added the columns I want to each content type, and I've made each content type available in my library and in my document sets.

I've tried:

1. Going into the content type through the Document Set and selecting the column, editing the site column, and selecting default value for each content type.
2. Going into the content type through the Document Library and selecting the column, editing the site column, and selecting default value for each content type.

Extensive searching here and elsewhere hasn't brought a solution. It seems I should be able to do what I need from one of the steps above but I haven't had any luck. What do I need to do to get default values to appear?

Comment: Hi Eric, are you sure about it being possible to set the default value depending on content type? Im not too sure about that. But none the less I have had a similar issue once, where the columns from the content type added to the document set content type didnt get published to the library. I manually added the column, and fitted rigth into the hiearchy of the document set/document content type and had the default value as it should (choice type column).

Comment: That is a good question, I'm fairly confident I had it set up like that but it has been a long time...maybe it just isn't possible and that's why I can't get it working! Thanks for the response.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Is it SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server 2013/2016,/2019?

Comment: We're using Microsoft 365